# A cohomological variant of the second Riemann's extension theorem

Tags: complex-geometry, cv.complex-variables

Let $X$ be a connected compact complex manifold, $U$ an open subset of $X$ such that the complement of $U$ in $X$ is an analytic subset of codimension at least 2 in $X$. Let $O_X$ (resp. $O_U$) be the sheaf of holomorphic functions on $X$ (resp. on $U$). If $n$ is a nonnegative integer then there is a natural  homomorphism of complex vector spaces

$$r_n: H^n(X,O_X) \to H^n(U,O_U).$$

The second Riemann extension theorem actually asserts that $r_n$ is an isomorphism for $n=0$. I am looking for a reference where it is proven that $r_n$ is  an isomorphism, say, for $n=1$ or $2$ (may be, under some additional assumptions). Thanks!

Comment: An algebraic version of this could be found in [EGA IV. 4ème partie](http://www.numdam.org/item/PMIHES_1967__32__5_0.pdf) Remarque 19.9.9. The idea seems to exploit the local cohomology.

Comment: A large part of [SGA 2](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0511279.pdf) is devoted to this. There is a long exact sequence involving $r_n$ where the extra terms are $H^{i}_Z(X,\mathscr{O}_X)$ (with $Z:=X\smallsetminus U$), and some criteria for the vanishing of these groups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first cohomology statement, you need the codimension to be at least three and for the first and second cohomology, codimension four. This theorem was proved by G Scheja in [1]. You can also find a proof in the book by Banica and Stanasila ([2] Chapter II, §II.3 pages 66-67).

**References**

[1] Constantin Banica, Octavian Stanasila, *Algebraic methods in the global theory of complex spaces*. Rev. English ed. (English) Bucuresti: Editura Academiei; London-New York-Sydney: John Wiley&Sons, pp. 296 (1976), [MR0463470](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR0463470), [Zbl 0334.32001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0334.32001).

[2] Günter Scheja, "Riemannsche Hebbarkeitssätze für Cohomologieklassen" (German) Mathematische Annalen 144, 345-360 (1961), [MR0148941](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR0148941), [Zbl 0112.38001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0112.38001).